# right way of PDO queries

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, pdo

this is my connection class.

```
class Database {
    private $host;
    private $port;
    private $dbname;
    private $username;
    private $password;

    function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password) {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=$this->host port=$this->port dbname=$this->dbname", "$this->username", "$this->password");
            echo "PDO connection object created";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}

$db = new Database('host','5432','eu','eu','eu');
```

Can you help me with doing right QUERY class which will be safe from sql injections?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as you use prepared statements you are safe, and no string escaping needed.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php and the rest of the pdo manual for that matter.  One of many very complete tutorials here:  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: It is not the query class that needs to be safe from injection, it is your queries. Unless you use an ORM / automatic query builder (or for some reason build your own), you need to understand a *technique* for writing safe queries, such as parameterised queries or correctly escaped inputs.

Comment: There are lots of good tips on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 Don't just read the most highly-rated answer, read them all, get a feel for the problems and the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I took out all the useless stuff from your class and added desired query. It will provide as much protection as PDO itself.

```
class Database
{
    function __construct($host, $port, $dbname, $username, $password) {
        $dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$dbname";
        $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    }
    function query($query, $bind) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($bind);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
$db   = new Database('host','5432','eu','eu','eu');
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE age > ? AND sex = ?";
$stmt = $db->query($sql, array(20,'F'));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out [this excellent tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) from Tutsplus. They cover what you need (prepared statements) and more there! I would also suggest `extend`ing PDO rather than making a wrapper class - it's generally more flexible.